# Lines in joined objects only in rendered animation

Tags: rendering

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the joined lines in the rendered animation. This is how the mesh looks and is fine without lines:[image]
This is how the rendered animation looks and is showing the lines (in red)[image]

I tried reversing the normals but it didn't change anything.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This almost looks like a second object clipping through? Do you have any other objects in the scene that could be appearing when you render?

Comment: please provide blend file